# File is not opening automatically in Safari after download

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to download the file. My requirement is to open file automatically once the download is completed.

```
var l_base64data = l_filetype + l_string
var a  = document.createElement('a')
a.href = l_base64data
a.download = l_filename
a.click()
```

It's working fine in Chrome and Firefox but it's not working in Safari. Kindly suggest if there is anything I am missing any browser specific code.

Thanks,
Lakshman

Comment: This code does not say "Open the file". It only says "Download the file". There is no instruction to open it. I'm not even sure how the file opens from Chrome or FF, maybe some default setting in the browser?

Comment: Whether the file opens in the browser or is just downloaded depends largely on the browser's settings and capabilities - whether it knows how to open that file type, what settings the user has enabled, and what headers are set by the server for the downloaded file

Comment: @ADyson, Yes actually safari browser has the settings "Open Safe files after downloading" enabled but still it's not opening after download, I wonder I may be missing headers for the file, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: what type of file are you testing with specifically?